# Laravel Faker Unknown formatter

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I have tried everything possible but I could not get to the bottom of what I am doing wrong. I am trying to load my database with dummy data but I keep get unknown formatter "description". Description is one of the variables I am using.

Below is my factory code and my seeder coder

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Analytics\Blockgrant;

$factory->define(Blockgrant::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'description' => $faker->description,
        'value' => $faker->value
    ];
});
```

---

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Universityobfanalytics\Blockgrantcomponents;

$factory->define(Blockgrantcomponents::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'blockgrants_id' => $faker->blockgrants_id,
        'description' => $faker->description,
        'percentage' => $faker->percentage,
        'value' => $faker->value
    ];
});
```

---

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Analytics\Blockgrant;
use Analytics\Blockgrantcomponents;

class BlockgrantSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(Blockgrant::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($blockgrant) {
            $blockgrant->blockgrantcomponents()->save(factory(Blockgrantcomponents::class)->create());

        });
    }
}
```

I am using a one to one `hasOne` and `belongsTo` relationship

Can somebody please assist by telling me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure `$faker->blockgrants_id` is available in the library ?

Comment: Does faker have description?

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/ to see available methods

Comment: More specifically formatters. https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#formatters You can use `$faker->sentence` or `realText` for description. `randomNumber` for value and percentages, and so on.

Answer (score 67):

It can be because you are using `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` instead of `Tests\TestCase` in your test.

Comment: This answer helped me fix my own problem. It should be marked as correct

Comment: This is the correct solution thank you.

Comment: thank you! your answer helped me!

Comment: Its not posible to use faker without Tests\TestCase? For example in a unit test

Comment: Your solution solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: simple and nice, works

Answer (score 3):

I am using [Pest](https://pestphp.com/) and was getting the same error when trying to write **unit tests** in my project, my solution:

In the file `tests/Pest.php`, I had a line like this:

```
uses(Tests\TestCase::class)->in('Feature');
```

I changed it to this and it worked

```
uses(Tests\TestCase::class)->in('Feature', 'Unit');
```

In the class`Test/TestCase`, remember to call `parent::setup()` in the constructor, like this:

```
 protected function setUp(): void
{
    try {
        parent::setUp();
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        file_put_contents(
            getcwd() . '/testing_env_log',
            json_encode([
                'db' => Config::get('database'),
                'env' => $_ENV,
                'app' => Config::get('app'),
            ], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)
        );

        throw $e;
    }
    Event::fake();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had forgotten to run the `parent::setUp()` function in the child class's `setUp()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own TestCase class, which will use the CreatesApplication trait you created. 
All this will look like this:

```
class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
}
```

```
trait CreatesApplication
{
    public function createApplication(): Application
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 - if use tests**

Check in test `setUp`, do you call `parent::setUp()`.

```
protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->setUpBannedUsersList();
}
```

**Solution 2**
Try create and use new faker:

```
$faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
```

Example

```
class UserFactory extends Factory
{    
    protected $model = User::class;

    public function definition(): array
    {
        //Instead of using $this->faker use new created $faker

        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

        return [
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'password' => Hash::make($faker->password),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare "description" like paragraph, that's all. I hope this information be useful:

```
        'description' => $faker->paragraph
```