# Getting InvalidArgumentException - Unknown format from fakerphp/faker library in laravel while testing in custom testsuite using pest

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, pestphp

I am using [Pest](https://pestphp.com/) library to write tests in laravel. I created the `my-laravel-application/tests/Integration` directory in laravel
and defined a new test suite in `phpunit.xml`

```
<testsuite name="Integration">
   <directory suffix=".test.php">./tests/Integration</directory>
</testsuite>
```

So that laravel acknowledges the test files in Integration directory and I could write my integration tests in a separate directory with a proper name(Integration directory), And I put my test files in the `my-laravel-application/tests/Integration` directory and I got the following error while running `php artisan test`:

```
InvalidArgumentException - Unknown format "name"
vendor/fakerphp/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:657
```

which indicates that the `$this->faker->name()` line of code in my `UserFactory` (I am using UserFactory class in my tests) has something wrong with, it says that name() method does not exist on $this->faker. But my tests used to work fine, before  moving them to `my-laravel-application/tests/Integration` directory. What is the real problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099021/laravel-faker-unknown-formatter#answer-65864888). You should enforce the use of `Tests\TestCase` (instead of `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`) for all the tests written in your newly created directory (Integration directory) by adding the following code to `/tests/Pest.test`:

```
uses(Tests\TestCase::class)->in('Integration');
```

Comment: It could also be that this happens because the factory is called from a `beforeAll()` hook. `beforeAll()` runs before the instantiation of the test class and has no access to factories. You should call your factories in `beforeEach()` instead. I got this information from a Github issue: https://github.com/pestphp/pest/issues/446

Answer (score 0):

This thread saved me lots of time.

I made sure an using right test case in the entire test dir...

```
uses(Tests\TestCase::class)->in(__DIR__);
```